# Is it possible (how difficult) to find MORE than one valid RSA signature?

Tags: rsa, signature

Is it possible (how difficult) to find more than one valid RSA signatures for a given message `m` (after padded) and a public key `e` (with the private key `d` known). Apparently signing `m` with `d` gives one valid signature. My question is how difficult to find another one. Thanks.

Comment: Depends entirely on the padding method.  With any nondetermanistic padding method (e.g. PSS), it's easy.  With, say, PKCS#1.5, well, I suppose you could generate distinct signatures by using different hash functions (say, SHA-256 and SHA-512)

Comment: I am talking about hashed, padded message, i.e. the number to be taken to the power of `d`.

Comment: The answer depends on if A) signatures verifiable by different public keys count; B) the scheme is deterministic [e.g. ISO/IEC 9796-2 methods 1 and 3] or not; C) access to the private key function $x\to x^d\bmod N$ is available; D) details in the verifier definition/implementation, e.g. is $S+N$ just as valid as $S$.

Comment: For a maliciously generated key with $\mathrm{GCD}(e, \phi(n))>1$ there should be several different values that become the same after raising to the $e$th power.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: actually, if $\operatorname{GCD}(e, \phi(n)) > 1$, then it's more likely that no such signature exists.  However, if one does exist, it is likely that many others do as well (if $e$ is prime, both $e$ and $e^2$ total are possible).

Comment: @poncho Which means that I can check that the signer didn't choose $\mathrm{GCD}(e,\phi(n))>1$ by asking for a certain number of signatures. This can be made non interactive with the usual hashing techniques. Still it's yet another pitfall for blind signature schemes, made particularly annoying since they are often used with multiple public exponents.

Comment: @CodesInChaos So GCD$(e, \phi(n)) = 1$ is a sufficient condition of unique solution?

Comment: @CodesInChaos : $\:$ Alternatively, one can choose [large prime public exponents](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-34961-4_25). $\hspace{1.59 in}$